# GitPython use email and pass in the script

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I must add my user and pass github into the code. Is it possible?
I mean I need to login every time I run the script but using the user and pass I have in the code:

code:

```
from git import Repo

def add_files():
    user = 'martinbouhier'
    pass = '123pass'
    repo_dir = 'python'
    if os.path.exists(repo_dir):
        shutil.rmtree(repo_dir)
    git_url = 'https://github.com/martinbouhier/python'
    Repo.clone_from(git_url, repo_dir)
    shutil.copy(file_klip, repo_dir)
    os.remove(file_klip)
    os.chdir(repo_dir)
    repo = Repo()
    commit_message = 'Actualizacion'
    repo.index.add([file_klip])
    repo.index.commit(commit_message)
    origin = repo.remote('origin')
    origin.push()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343146/7976758

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+user+password+http